# What is classic object oriented programming?

Tags: object-oriented, terminology

I heard the phrase *classic object oriented programming*. Is it different from present object oriented programming, like classic ASP and ASP.net?

Comment: It is likely a reference to a style used in Simula or Smalltalk.

Comment: Classing ASP is an older web platform by Microsoft - it uses VBScript or JScript as the basic programming languages, which are not fully object oriented. ASP.NET is a modern platform that can be used with any .NET language such as C# and VB.NET which _are_ object oriented.

Comment: @Oded i am not asked difference between classic asp and asp.net.. i am asking is there any versions for OO or not. Means only classic OO only existing from long time..!!

Comment: The question has a confusing statement (due to the different contexts of "classic"). I was simply adding that context.

Comment: Where did you hear this phrase?  Without context answers are going to be all over the place.

Answer (score 3):

I've only heard the term classical OO when used to distinguish between the class based OO you find in Java and the [prototype based OO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) you find in JavaScript. The term doesn't refer to an outdated style.

It is completely unrelated to Classic ASP / ASP.NET where "Classic" means "I really mean ASP and am not using it as a shorthand for ASP.NET".

Comment: The Java-style of OO should probably be called "class-based OO" if you want to distinguish it from prototype-based OO. I don't think it's any more or less classic than prototype-based OO. Both class-based and prototype-based OO have a fairly long history.

Comment: It's possible he misheard someone say "class-based object oriented programming".

Comment: "Classical OO" is a common phrase in JavaScript circles.